# mysql_connect access denied error when trying to access remote database

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to connect to a remote database.  Here's my code:-

```
php $con = mysql_connect("2toria.com","username","password"); if (!$con)   {   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());   }

mysql_select_db("myTable", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Contestants");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))   {   echo $row['Name'];   echo "<br />";   }

mysql_close($con);
```

The database, table, username and password names are all correct (I've changed them here for obvious reasons), but I'm getting the following error:-

> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for
> user 'username'@'bluechip6.ukhost4u.com' (using password: YES) in
> /home/toriaco/public_html/bigbro/index.php on line 9 Could not
> connect: Access denied for user 'username'@'bluechip6.ukhost4u.com'
> (using password: YES)**

Comment: This looks normal: hosting providers usually close mySQL databases for external connections for security reasons. Is the database explicitly supposed to be accessible?

Comment: Yes, and it's not an external connection, it's part of the hosting I've got, so I should be able to access it.  I can use the same username and password credentials with the MYSQL GUI tools and get to my database that way.  What I need to do is query the database and return rows, as shown.

Comment: Then why don;t you connect to "localhost" instead of "2toria.com"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First possible reason:
I know antagonist (a Dutch hosting service) blocks all connections that are not from `localhost` for security reasons, and I don't think they are the only ones. (So always connect to localhost, not a `http://...` URL!)

Second possible reason:
The password/username is wrong.

Comment: The localhost thing worked perfectlym, thanks.  Another quick question - How is the password/username wrong?  Can you enlighten me - as I said, Im new to this.

Comment: @Mat he meant it as two different possibilities. If localhost worked for you, there's nothing else to do

Comment: If the localhost thing worked, you should acccept this answer

Comment: Apologies, I misread the second reason.  Thanks for your help - answer accepted!!